# What are free CDNs that don't force changing DNS?

Tags: cloud-service, web-server, dns

CloudFlare CDN has a free plan, but it wants users to use its CloudFlare's DNS.

Incapsula does not force users to change DNS (see https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/43821), but it is not completely free (see https://www.incapsula.com/pricing-and-plans.html).

Does anyone know any CDN provider that has a free plan and doesn't force changing DNS?